# How do I manage a collection of fastcgi processes on mono

Tags: nginx, servicestack, fastcgi-mono-server

When dealing with multiple nginx websites proxying through to fastcgi-mono-server4 processes, do I need to manage each separate fastcgi process for each website or is there a way to collectively associate a pool of fastcgi processes with the nginx virtual host config? I've not had any luck googling this, so far I've managed to run multiple service stack services each on their own fastcgi process - just hoping there's a cleaner way to manage the fastcgi side of things.

Thanks

Comment: I self host the ServiceStack applications on different localhost ports, then proxy the connection from nginx. I find this far more reliable than using fastcgi and mono-server4. I also use `supervisord` to ensure the application always remains up.

Comment: cheers , nice suggestion - i think ill self host everything not just the apis - will end up being much easier

Comment: Have you looked into mono-fpm?